# Where should markdown parsing code live in a Django app?

Tags: python, django, markdown, wmd-editor

I am using WMD editor in the django admin. I have written a simple parser (regex mostly) so I can catch specific tags in the markdown and insert HTML accordingly. My problem is that I need access to the Django object itself.

Currently I'm overriding `Model.save()` and calling `Model.process_markdown()`

```
def process_markdown(self):
    p = re.compile("\[\[\s*(?P<tag>image):(?P<id>[\d,]+)\s*\]\]")
    processed = p.sub(partial(render_markdown, self), self.body_markdown)
    return markdown.markdown(processed)
```

The result is then saved into a `Model.rendered` field on my model. If you notice I have a `render_markdown` function being called. Thats stored in a file called `util.py` in my app and does all the real work.

Everything is working but this seems like there should be a better way. I know I can tie into markdown for custom tags and do this a cleaner but I have to beable to access the django object and I as I reference related inline objects. As far as I can tell there is not a way for me to do this.

Is there a better way to organize this?

Answer (score 0):

Beware that markdown allows HTML to be tunneled through.  If you do this, you probably want markdown(html, safe_mode='escape')  If you're allowing untrusted sources to insert .body_markdown, you will need to sanitize that input via something like bleach: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bleach

Comment: The only people that post are trusted employees so luckily I don't have to sanitize to that degree. Thanks for your help!